# NSDictionary returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a `NSMutableDictionary` with a `NSDictionary` as the value and they key is set to a year.

So when I debug my code, my `_codes` variable, the `NSMutableDictionary` returns
Printing description of self->_codes:

```
{
    2013 =     {
        Depth = "21.5";
        RValue = R59;
        year = 2013;
    };
    2014 =     {
        Depth = "22.25";
        RValue = R60;
        year = 2014;
    };
}
```

but when I try to access it via:

```
NSDictionary *test = [_codes objectForKey:@"2014"];
```

`test` is always nil.

Anybody have any idea why?

Comment: It's unclear from the dump whether your key values are NSString or NSNumber values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the key is a NSNumber, not a NSString

Try:

```
NSDictionary *test = [_codes objectForKey:@2014];
```

or, more succinctly and modern:

```
NSDictionary *test = _codes[@2014];
```

Comment: This worked thank you! I tried `NSDictionary *test = [_codes objectForKey:2014];` before without the @

Answer (score 0):

Try:

[_codes objectForKey:[NSNumber numberFromInt:2014]];